# VB.Net Fill List with SQL Query

Tags: vb.net, oledb

I'm trying to fill either a combobox or a list with an sql query, I can get them to produce the number of entries pulled but not the names of the entries, and not multiple entries.

The code in question is simple:

```
 Dim RegisterApt As New StudentsDataSetTableAdapters.TestTableAdapter


    Try

        txtTestPull.Items.Add(RegisterApt.FillByStudentsTest(StudentsDataSet.Test, StudentInsert.School, StudentInsert.School))




    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

What I can't seem to find online is how to do this.
All I'd like to do is pull results using my sql query which I know works,
and push the resulting rows to the list or combobox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the step by step on how to fill a ComboBox and a DataGridView using ADO.Net. I use the Northwind database as a sample.

## 1. Add a DataSet

[image]

Right-click your project and choose `Add`, then choose `New Item`. Choose `Dataset` in the next window.

## 2. Add a DataTable

[image]

Connect to your database and drag a table into the middle area. In this example, I choose the Customers table.

## 3. Add a query

[image]

- Right-click your DataTable, and choose `Add`, then choose `Query`.
- Choose `Use SQL statements` in the next window, click `Next`.
- Choose `SELECT which returns rows` in the next window, click `Next`.

## 4. Write a query

[image]

```
SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName, ContactTitle, Address, City, Region, PostalCode, Country, Phone, Fax
FROM dbo.Customers
WHERE Country = @Country
```

- I add a WHERE clause to filter the data. Click `Next`.
- Gives names to your methods. I use `FillByCountry` in the first textbox and `GetDataByCountry` in the second textbox.
- Save your project and build it first because you're adding a new DataSet.

## 5. Add some controls in your form

[image]

Add a Button, a TextBox, a ComboBox and a DataGridView. You can change the names, but I use the default names in this example.

## 6. Write some code to get the data and bind it to ComboBox and DataGridView

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        ' declare a DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataSet1.CustomersDataTable

        ' declare a DataAdapter
        Dim da As New DataSet1TableAdapters.CustomersTableAdapter
        ' use the DataAdapter to fill the DataTable
        da.FillByCountry(dt, TextBox1.Text)

        ' bind the DataTable to a DataGridView
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

        ' bind the DataTable to a ComboBox
        ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "CustomerID"
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "CompanyName"

    End Sub

End Class
```

## 7. Run the project and see the result

[image]